# Determine connections of a transformer based on resistance

Tags: transformer, resistance

I have a small transformer I desoldered from a disposable camera that transformed 1.5V to high voltage >90V. It has three leads on one side and two on the other. I have been testing its resistance and got the following measurements[image: Resistance] (***There is an error** the resistance from connection 4 : 2 is 270 ohms not 3 ohms)
The 3rd lead seems to be connected to the smaller coil but there is glue and I cannot figure out the other connections.[image: Transformer] Sorry for the really terrible solder joints (working on it).

Comment: So when you test between any two pins you never get infinite resistance??

Comment: Hello, I am glad someone revived this thread since I was never able to figure it out. There is infinite resistance between pins 3 and 4, 5 and 4. and between 1 and 3, 1 and 5, 2 and 3, 2 and 5. It seems a bit strange that the middle lead (pin 4) has a different resistance to pin 1 and pin 2 but between pin 1 and pin 2 they have the same resistance

Comment: I don't understand why you have 4:2 twice, with two different values.

Comment: 4:2 resistance is about 3 ohms

Comment: Then what does this mean: "(*There is an error the resistance from connection 4 : 2 is 270 ohms not 3 ohms)"?

Comment: Yes I apologize, 4:2 is 3 ohms 4:1 is 270 ohms, and 1:2 is 270 ohms. I tried to apply a pwm signal and I am certain I tried all the logical combinations and had no luck measuring voltage.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Sam Goldwasser's FAQ](http://repairfaq.cis.upenn.edu/sam/strbfaq.htm) on strobes and camera flashes- it's quite an extensive collection. With credit to Sam and the original author, here is a typical circuit:

[image]

It appears your 3:5 is the drive coil and the high voltage and feedback windings are the remaining three pins with 2 the high voltage output. Up to you to figure out the phasing, and I'm not really sure from those measurements which end of the feedback coil goes where- try to use a higher resolution meter and take the measurements all at the same time (and temperature). 3 ohms is only about 1% of the high voltage winding...